# Chrome websocket dev tools doesn't have hex viewer

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, development-environment

I found there is no hex viewer in my Chrome's WebSocket dev tools, as in picture 2, unlike picture 1 on my colleague's computer.

I didn't find corresponding view settings. I tried to reboot my computer and reinstall Chrome, even the beta version, still not work.

Thanks to someone who would help me out!

OS version: macOS Catalina 10.15.7, Chrome version: 87.0.4280.88

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0I0t.png) normal view

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeRuW.png) no encoding settings

Comment: I don't have an answer but I recommend rephrasing your question and post to include that phrase hex viewer (or whatever the name of that dropdown is) to help people find this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome 87. I suspect that your colleague is using a different Chrome version.

See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151164#c7, which claims that the bug was fixed in Chrome 89.0.4348.0. The solution appears to be one of:

1. Switch to the Chrome Beta channel
2. Use a debug extension for Chrome such as [WebSocket Frame Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websocket-frame-inspector/nlajeopfbepekemjhkjcbbnencojpaae/related) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474220/chrome-devtools-the-encoding-switch-bar-of-the-websocket-frame-viewer-disappear?rq=1).

See also these related SO questions:

- [How can I change the binary message display format in the Chrome/Edge debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959496/how-can-i-change-the-binary-message-display-format-in-the-chrome-edge-debugger/65961644#65961644)
- [Chrome DevTools. The encoding switch bar of the websocket frame viewer disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474220/chrome-devtools-the-encoding-switch-bar-of-the-websocket-frame-viewer-disappear?rq=1)