# Chrome DevTools. The encoding switch bar of the websocket frame viewer disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome 87

In Chrome DevTools, there should be a bottom bar for switching message encoding (binary hex view, text, or base64), but now I can't find it in my Chrome, and all messages are automatically base64-encoded (they should be binary messages and I want them to be displayed in Hex). How can I solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H97sx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be a bug in [Chrome 87](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151164). According to the [latest comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151164#c7), the issue was fixed in Chrome 89.

Comment: After done a little search I found a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websocket-frame-inspector/nlajeopfbepekemjhkjcbbnencojpaae/related) that in the mean time the one may utilize which offers hexadecimal viewing of a binary WebSocket frame, as someone like me may not want to opt-in the Beta channel of Chrome :D