# How can I change the binary message display format in the Chrome/Edge debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, microsoft-edge

In this release announcement about the Chrome debugger capabilities https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/devtools, Kayce Basques writes:

> Use the dropdown menu at the bottom of the viewer to convert the message into Base64 or UTF-8. Click Copy to clipboard Copy to clipboard to copy the binary message to your clipboard.

Figure 8 shows a bar with the words "Hex Viewer": [image: Figure 8 from What's New In DevTools (Chrome 74), displaying binary messages in UTF-8 format]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2019/03/binary4.png))</sub>

In Chrome Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (x86_64) and Edge Version 88.0.705.53 (Official build) (64-bit), on MacOS, this bar doesn't seem to exist:

### Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot without format bar]

### Edge:

[image: Edge Screenshot without format bar]

Is there a way to view binary websocket messages in a format other than base64 in the latest Chrome/Edge network debuggers, or has this functionality been removed entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered this chromium bug that appears to be fixed in Chrome 89.0.4348.0.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151164#c7

This is also answered in [Chrome DevTools. The encoding switch bar of the websocket frame viewer disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474220/chrome-devtools-the-encoding-switch-bar-of-the-websocket-frame-viewer-disappear?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.